# Dailymotion Upload via .NET

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any library to upload videos to DailyMotion using .NET?

Comment: Even if there aren't, there are plenty of OAuth2 and REST libraries you can probably chain together, e.g [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/)

Comment: See the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969219/how-to-upload-video-on-dailymotion-with-c-sharp-is-somebody-has-a-complete-co

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While looking for the Dailymotion API i found this description

http://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/getting-started.html#getting-started-publishing-videos

Comment: Unfortunately, the Dailymotion API has no ready-to-use .NET implementation, that means I'd have to write it myself. I'd like to know if there is any solution that I can just plug into my project and use.