# How to upload video on Dailymotion with c# ?? Is somebody has a complete code?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wish upload a video on dailymotion with c# code , but dailymotion doesn't provide c# code to upload video with c#.

I search on dailymotion documentation api and i found this not explicit curl code :

```
curl -F 'access_token=...' \
     -F 'url=http://upload-02.dailymotion.com/files/5ccb48b8e8aef3fcb8959739f993e1b9.3gp' \
     https://api.dailymotion.com/me/videos
```

and i tryed to transpose but it's not working:

```
 string contentFile = "c:\name_of_my_video_file.flv";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(contentFile);
            MemoryStream fs = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

            // Provide the WebPermission Credintials
            // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
            string uri = "https://api.dailymotion.com/me/videos";
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
            // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("logindailymotion","passworddailymotion");

            // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
            string postData = "access_token=my_api_key&url=http://upload-02.dailymotion.com/files/name_of_my_video_file.flv";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            // Get the request stream.

            // Notify the server about the size of the uploaded file
            request.ContentLength = fs.Length;

            // The buffer size is set to 2kb
            int buffLength = 2048;
            byte[] buff = new byte[buffLength];
            int contentLen;

            // Opens a file stream (System.IO.FileStream) to read the file to be uploaded
            //FileStream fs = fileInf.OpenRead();

            try
            {
                // Stream to which the file to be upload is written
                Stream strm = request.GetRequestStream();

                // Read from the file stream 2kb at a time
                contentLen = fs.Read(buff, 0, buffLength);

                // Till Stream content ends
                while (contentLen != 0)
                {
                    // Write Content from the file stream to the FTP Upload Stream
                    strm.Write(buff, 0, contentLen);
                    contentLen = fs.Read(buff, 0, buffLength);
                }

                // Close the file stream and the Request Stream
                strm.Close();
                fs.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

        }
```

Is there a better documentation for c# code ?

Is somebody has the correct code ?

Comment: i don't know about the upload part but are you using ASCII for video file??
 - isn't it better to use File.ReadAllBytes() instead ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I created a complete example to answer your question and upload a video. It is available [on GitHub](https://github.com/cbenard/SODailyMotionUpload) now.

**Edit:** I used API information available explaining how to do their [OAuth Authentication](http://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/authentication.html) and [Video Publishing](http://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/getting-started.html#publishing-videos).

Here is all the code except for the objects that are deserialized from JSON:

**Code**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var accessToken = GetAccessToken();
        Authorize(accessToken);

        Console.WriteLine("Access token is " + accessToken);

        var fileToUpload = @"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\en-US\join.avi";

        Console.WriteLine("File to upload is " + fileToUpload);

        var uploadUrl = GetFileUploadUrl(accessToken);

        Console.WriteLine("Posting to " + uploadUrl);

        var response = GetFileUploadResponse(fileToUpload, accessToken, uploadUrl);

        Console.WriteLine("Response:\n");

        Console.WriteLine(response + "\n");

        Console.WriteLine("Publishing video.\n");
        var uploadedResponse = PublishVideo(response, accessToken);

        Console.WriteLine(uploadedResponse);

        Console.WriteLine("Done. Press enter to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static UploadResponse GetFileUploadResponse(string fileToUpload, string accessToken, string uploadUrl)
    {
        var client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "OAuth " + accessToken);

        var responseBytes = client.UploadFile(uploadUrl, fileToUpload);

        var responseString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);

        var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UploadResponse>(responseString);

        return response;
    }

    private static UploadedResponse PublishVideo(UploadResponse uploadResponse, string accessToken)
    {
        var request = WebRequest.Create("https://api.dailymotion.com/me/videos?url=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(uploadResponse.url));
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "OAuth " + accessToken);

        var requestString = String.Format("title={0}&tags={1}&channel={2}&published={3}",
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode("some title"),
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode("tag1"),
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode("news"),
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode("true"));

        var requestBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestString);

        var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();

        requestStream.Write(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length);

        var response = request.GetResponse();

        var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        string responseString;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        var uploadedResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UploadedResponse>(responseString);
        return uploadedResponse;
    }

    private static string GetAccessToken()
    {
        var request = WebRequest.Create("https://api.dailymotion.com/oauth/token");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        var requestString = String.Format("grant_type=password&client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&username={2}&password={3}",
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(SettingsProvider.Key),
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(SettingsProvider.Secret),
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(SettingsProvider.Username),
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(SettingsProvider.Password));

        var requestBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestString);

        var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();

        requestStream.Write(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length);

        var response = request.GetResponse();

        var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        string responseString;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        var oauthResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OAuthResponse>(responseString);

        return oauthResponse.access_token;
    }

    private static void Authorize(string accessToken)
    {
        var authorizeUrl = String.Format("https://api.dailymotion.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={0}&scope=read+write+manage_videos+delete&redirect_uri={1}",
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(SettingsProvider.Key),
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(SettingsProvider.CallbackUrl));

        Console.WriteLine("We need permissions to upload. Press enter to open web browser.");
        Console.ReadLine();

        Process.Start(authorizeUrl);

        var client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "OAuth " + accessToken);

        Console.WriteLine("Press enter once you have authenticated and been redirected to your callback URL");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static string GetFileUploadUrl(string accessToken)
    {
        var client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "OAuth " + accessToken);

        var urlResponse = client.DownloadString("https://api.dailymotion.com/file/upload");

        var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UploadRequestResponse>(urlResponse).upload_url;

        return response;
    }
```

Again, [I put it on GitHub](https://github.com/cbenard/SODailyMotionUpload).

Comment: I compile and execute your code and the program do a good treatment without errors , (see the console result at : http://www.dz-axium.com/dailymotion.png ). But noting happened : no video uploaded.

Comment: @user1018697, turns out you need extra authorization, which has to be performed by the user and then they will be redirected. I updated the application on GitHub, and now in secrets.xml, you need to set your callbackurl **exactly** as it is set in your DailyMotion Developer settings, e.g. `http://site.com/path/to/file.aspx` or whatever. Please re-download and try again, and please accept if this solves your issue.