# The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. during post request...?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, post, httpwebrequest, http-status-code-403

I try to make small application for myself and I found this application
[How to upload video on Dailymotion with c# ?? Is somebody has a complete code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969219/how-to-upload-video-on-dailymotion-with-c-sharp-is-somebody-has-a-complete-co)

When I tried every thing but publishing is not working. I used fiddler but I cant find the error.
Here is the code

```
 var request = WebRequest.Create("https://api.dailymotion.com/me/videos?url=" + Uri.EscapeUriString(uploadResponse.url));
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "OAuth " + accessToken);

        var requestBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("title=test 123&channel=Funny&tags=Humor&description=Testing testing&published=true");

        var requestBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestString);

        var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();

        requestStream.Write(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length);

        var response = request.GetResponse();

        var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        string responseString;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

When it reaches request.GetResponse() it gives the error. So what is the problem here..?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to get rid of the "me" in the url as you're using OAuth instead of basic authentication, like this:

```
"https://api.dailymotion.com/videos?url="
```

Instead of:

```
"https://api.dailymotion.com/me/videos?url="
```

At least in a quick scan that looks like it's it, I wrote an auto-publisher for a client a year ago and it didn't use the `me` in the url. My credentials are invalid now, so can't test it unfortunately. It seems to be a bug in the answer you linked.

If you can read other languages, I found it helpful just going through their SDKs and converting the code:

http://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/sdk-php.html

https://github.com/dailymotion/dailymotion-sdk-php/blob/master/Dailymotion.php