# How to fix The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. dailymotion api

Tags: c#, http-status-code-403, dailymotion-api

So I am using the Dailymotion API for uploading the video and use the code I get from the [GitHub](https://github.com/cbenard/SODailyMotionUpload) and it works perfectly but after 4 videos it gives the exception:

{"The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."}

And I am getting an error in PublishVideo method

var response = request.GetResponse();

Main Code

```
        var accessToken = GetAccessToken();
        Authorize(accessToken);

        Console.WriteLine("Access token is " + accessToken);

        var fileToUpload = @"E:\Courses\[FreeCourseSite.com] Udemy - Entity Framework in Depth The Complete Guide\3. Building a Model using Database-First Workflow\11. Summary.mp4";

        Console.WriteLine("File to upload is " + fileToUpload);

        var uploadUrl = GetFileUploadUrl(accessToken);

        Console.WriteLine("Posting to " + uploadUrl);

        var response = GetFileUploadResponse(fileToUpload, accessToken, uploadUrl);

        Console.WriteLine("Response:\n");

        Console.WriteLine(response + "\n");

        Console.WriteLine("Publishing video.\n");
        var uploadedResponse = PublishVideo(response, accessToken);

        Console.WriteLine(uploadedResponse);

        Console.WriteLine("Done. Press enter to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static UploadResponse GetFileUploadResponse(string fileToUpload, string accessToken, string uploadUrl)
    {
        var client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "OAuth " + accessToken);

        var responseBytes = client.UploadFile(uploadUrl, fileToUpload);

        var responseString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);

        var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UploadResponse>(responseString);

        return response;
    }

    private static UploadedResponse PublishVideo(UploadResponse uploadResponse, string accessToken)
    {
        var request = WebRequest.Create("https://api.dailymotion.com/me/videos?url=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(uploadResponse.url));
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "OAuth " + accessToken);

        var requestString = String.Format("title={0}&tags={1}&channel={2}&private={3}&published={4}",
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode("123123123"),
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode("tag1"),
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode("news"),
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode("true"),
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode("true"));

        var requestBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestString);

        var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();

        requestStream.Write(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length);



        var response = request.GetResponse();

        var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        string responseString;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        var uploadedResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UploadedResponse>(responseString);
        return uploadedResponse;
    }

    private static string GetAccessToken()
    {
        var request = WebRequest.Create("https://api.dailymotion.com/oauth/token");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        var requestString = String.Format("grant_type=password&client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&username={2}&password={3}",
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(SettingsProvider.Key),
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(SettingsProvider.Secret),
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(SettingsProvider.Username),
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(SettingsProvider.Password));

        var requestBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestString);

        var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();

        requestStream.Write(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length);

        var response = request.GetResponse();

        var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        string responseString;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        var oauthResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OAuthResponse>(responseString);

        return oauthResponse.access_token;
    }

    private static void Authorize(string accessToken)
    {
        var authorizeUrl = String.Format("https://api.dailymotion.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={0}&scope=read+write+manage_videos+delete&redirect_uri={1}",
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(SettingsProvider.Key),
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(SettingsProvider.CallbackUrl));

        Console.WriteLine("We need permissions to upload. Press enter to open web browser.");
        Console.ReadLine();

        Process.Start(authorizeUrl);

        var client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "OAuth " + accessToken);

        Console.WriteLine("Press enter once you have authenticated and been redirected to your callback URL");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static string GetFileUploadUrl(string accessToken)
    {
        var client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "OAuth " + accessToken);

        var urlResponse = client.DownloadString("https://api.dailymotion.com/file/upload");

        var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UploadRequestResponse>(urlResponse).upload_url;

        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11565057/2946329

Comment: I check this and it is not working for me and does not solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

It could be related to many causes. I suggest you to catch the error and get the response stream from our API:

```
    try{
            var response = request.GetResponse();
            var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            string responseString;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            {
                responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            var uploadedResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UploadedResponse>(responseString);
            return uploadedResponse;
        }
        catch(WebException e){

            var rs = e.Response.GetResponseStream();
            string errorResponseString;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(rs))
            {
                errorResponseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            Console.WriteLine(errorResponseString);  
            return null;  
        }
```

You will get a message explaining you why your access is forbidden.
I also invite you to check our API rate limit rules which can be a cause of forbidden call: https://developer.dailymotion.com/api/#rate-limit

Comment: Thanks for the answer I think I have exceeded my quota.
I read on google 
To prevent spam, all Dailymotion users are limited to: 10 uploads per day. 2 hours of video per day. 60 minutes per video.