# How to Directly Upload file to other server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload

So I have a project in which i want to upload video to dailymotion using api

So i want to Upload video directly to dailymotion server without uploading it to my local server

My Action

```
 [HttpPost]
 public async Task<ActionResult> Add(Video Videos)
 {
        var fileToUpload = @"E:\Courses\[FreeCourseLab.com] Udemy - C# Intermediate Classes, Interfaces and OOP\5. Polymorphism Third Pillar of OOP\3. Sealed Classes and Members.mp4";
        return RedirectToAction("AddVideo", "Admin");
 }
```

my View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "px-lg-4", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="input-group input-group--focus mb-lg-4" style="width: 100%">
        <div class="input-group-prepend"></div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Videos.File,  new {@type="file" })
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="d-flex justify-content-center btn btn-block btn-primary" value="Create" />  
}
```

Comment: Possibe duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969219/how-to-upload-video-on-dailymotion-with-c-sharp-is-somebody-has-a-complete-co)

Comment: yeah but i want to the file path of user selected file in FileToUpload variable so i directly upload it to dailymotion

Comment: You will just have to create a method that sets the value of `var fileToUpload` to the user selected file path or am I missing something?

Comment: yes method or anything i Only need file path so i directly upload it to dailymotion without uploading it to my localserver

Comment: if you use the code from the post I linked there is no need to upload anything to your local server, you will just upload it from the device your running your code on. If that code is running on your server however you will have to upload it to your server but you can basically work around that by uploading to your server but not actually storing the file on your server. You can just forward it to the dailymotion uploader. You will need large amounts of ram tho if you do that unless you will upload the file in chunks. Thats a tricky thing tho, i recommend you ask a new question

Comment: ok so how to throw it to dailymotion server with out storing the file any sample code please

Comment: no, i mean create an entirely new question where you refer to this question and the one i linked. You could name your question something like "how to upload to dailymotion" using chunked data" or "how to upload to dailymotion without storing data on transfer server" or something similar

Comment: okay thanks for the help I will create